# Haar functions question c

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be an integrable function on [0,1]. Prove that on any interval $J\subset[0,1]$ contained in some $I_{n,l}$ we have $$\frac{1}{|J|}\int_{J}f(x)dx = \sum_{j = 0}^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{2^{j} - 1}<f,h_{j,k}>h_{j,k}(x).$$

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: What is $I_{n,l}$? What is $h_{j,k}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  I think dyadic interval & Haar function respectively.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  dyadic interval and the Haar function associated with it.